# malicious js? or what is it

Tags: javascript, wordpress, external, malware

I am working on a customers website (wp), and i found something in the header that looks malicious - i have searched the web for what it is, but i cannot seem to find any answers - will you help me. The code that i found is

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.djkeun1bal.com/js/xxxx.js"></script>

<noscript><img src="http://www.djkeun1bal.com/xxxxx.png" style="display:none;" /></noscript>
```

I hope that you can help me here.

Comment: As-is http://www.djkeun1bal.com/js/71439.js returns nothing. I suspect it depends on the referrer.

Comment: I also noticed that it seems like an empty file - but a lot of website have refers to djkeun1bal.com/js - Is it something to worry about? is there any reason to have this, and not just delete it?

Comment: Maybe code that was inserted from an browser extension. The site redirects to http://www.leadforensics.com. Looks like an analytics tool.

Comment: If it doesn't belong there (check everyone who works or worked on the site) consider the site hacked. Dump everything and restore your backups. Better safe than sorry. Even if it doesn't download malicious code now, you can't be sure it won't do that in the future.

Comment: The thing is, that the site was just hacked, and i am in the process of cleaning it up - it is not inserted my a browser extention, it is directly in the header.php

Comment: How are you supposed to clean it up if you cannot determine what is malicious and what is not?

Comment: so far - backup the database, scanned it for the usual suspects, scanned the content folder, deleted all core files, installed new wp version, and am currently runnning anti-malware, sucuri and wordfence - But sometimes that is not enough, and i found this script - so i wanted to ask here, if anybody had seen it before, or knew what it did before deleting it.

Comment: This is a tracker, it returns no data but collects info about the visiting web browser. It looks unfinished or abandoned, but still functional.

Comment: so your suggestion is that i at least uncomment it after my scanning is done? the scanners did not suspect the script

Comment: If in doubt, rip it out.

Comment: For interested people, The script has been "ripped out, since in doubt" -and nothing broke. If somebody wants the points tomorrow, answer the question.

Comment: To all interested people - It seems that it was some sort of malishous code - The wordpress site was spamming emails, and getting bounces from undelivered. It seems to have stopped after removing this script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This tracking code is from a company called Lead Forensics - I added it a while ago to a customer site when they signed up to a trail with them.

I came across this question when searching for the djkeun1bal.com domain as I spotted the js when auditing their site and forgot I'd added it. They've done a good job of making it look malicious!

The number in the URLs is likely a customer ID with Lead Forensics - you may want to remove if from the SO question for privacy reasons.

Edited to add: www.djkeun1bal.com and tracker.leadforensics.com both resolve to lfvmeuw.cloudapp.net [104.40.215.103]. I'm not sure why they use two different domains. I guess one may be for privacy reasons, which I've just blown for them. Sorry!

Comment: So it really is nothing malicious - I have removed it from the site, since nobody could explain to me, what it did or why it was there - 
And since i removed it, wordpress stopped sending out spam - but i did clean the core etc. so maybe it was a coincidence. 
You are saying, that it was NOT suspecious?

Comment: Correct - it's not malicious. It's tracking code from this company - http://www.leadforensics.com/. Someone almost certainly added it intentionally, and will probably be wondering why their analytics have stopped working :)

Answer (score 1):

Lead Forensics uses random alias/masked domains so as to make it harder for web visitors to block them from tracking/snooping them.  There is no opt-out process.

If they stuck to their primary domain leadforensics.com then they could easily be blocked from a hosts file.  They have many obscure domains that they operate from and this decreases their chances of being blocked from data harvesting.

Comment: Not sure why this was marked down.  It answers the OP question.  I suspect it was by someone at Lead Forensics as the OP question was also marked down.